# R - Error message in doing rda analysis - vegan package

Tags: r, summary, vegan, rda

With this data frame grouping the response variables :

[image]

And this df grouping the explanatory variables :

[image]

I perform the vegan::rda like this :

```
fish_rda <- rda(fish ~ kJ_per_kg_GF + Condition(factor(annee)), data=df_rda)
```

But when I call `summary(fish_rda)`, it returns this error message :

**Error in if (all(vars >= 0)) cumsum(vars) else NA : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

I don't understand ...

Here, there is the output of the traceback function :

[image]

Someone to help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Please type `traceback()` after the error. It will print the path to the error message. The `summary` function for `rda` is not able to give this error message in **vegan**, but it must come from somewhere else. In general, we need a reproducible example to solve the problems.

Comment: Please make your problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). As it is, users can only speculate on possible issues.

Comment: I understand the need to reproduce the exemple. But this exemple seems to be a "special case" in which something doesn't work properly (maybe due to my proper data). That's why if I reproduce the exemple with a dataset of R (like iris data), the summary function will work

Comment: I still wait for the output of `traceback()`: it will tell us *in which* function the error happened.

Comment: It works ! The problem came from the condition variable. I deleted it and now the summary function works properly

Comment: I think the problem is that with Condition() the constraints were completely aliased. Is this so? If you just look at the result (type `fish_rda`) there will be line `Constrained    0.0000     0.0000    0` which means that constraints did not explain anything after Conditions were partialled out. At least I could generate your error message in such a case. This is a bug in **vegan** and I'll fix it.